# Getting two different outputs in two different apps?

Tags: c++, c++17, visual-studio-code, replit

When I run the code in replit I get the following output 1024, 512,0,0,0 but when I run it in VS Code I get 2,2,0,0,0. Is there something wrong with my VS Code C++ configuration.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <cctype>

using namespace std;
int main(){
string my_string;
cout << "Enter a string: " ;
getline(cin,my_string);
cout << isalpha(my_string[0]) << endl;
cout << islower(my_string[0]) << endl;
cout << isupper(my_string[0]) << endl;
cout << isdigit(my_string[0]) << endl;
cout << isspace(my_string[0]) << endl;
return 0;
}
```

Comment: What do you give as input? Anyhow these are C functions. 0=false,  !0 = true. I.e. depending on the platform it can be any value other than zero.  You need to `static_cast` the output to `bool`. And print using `boolalpha` or so.

Answer (score 3):

When those functions return a positive value, it can be any positive value. There are no guarantees about it being a particular positive value, nor that the value will always be the same positive value.

> Is there something wrong with my VS Code C++ configuration.

No; this is normal.